# How do you open an XML picture file?

Tags: xml, file

I have a digital elgph camera and accidently pressed something that turned all my pictures into XML files, they all show up on my computer but i cannot open them.  Is there any way i am able to open them?

Comment: You might have better luck on a canon or digital elph forum

Comment: You need to provide more details if you want to get an answer. What camera do you use, what operation system is on your computer, ...

Answer (score 1):

This XML should have [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded image data. You can try decoding this section of XML and write all bytes to disk. From there, you can more or less guess what is the format of the file by looking at first several bytes of the file (for instance PNG files have `%PNG` in the header, JPEGs have `JFIF` somewhere near the beginning, etc.)

Comment: Worth noting that you probably don't have a shot if you don't write software - unless anyone knows of any image editing software that reads XML?